# Why is the output None?

Tags: python, function

I have been playing around with functions and recursion and I don't understand why this would output None. I expected it to output [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] but even though there is an explicit return function it outputs None.

```
list = []
def func(x):
    x.append(1)
    if len(x) >10:
        return x
    else:
        func(x)

print (func(list))
```

Output:

```
None
```

Comment: the  `else` is redundant in a recursive function. Note that this is not a recursive function because it's not returning a function in any case.

Comment: You need to `return func(x)` in the recursive case. This is a common FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = []
def func(x):
    x.append(1)
    if len(x) > 10:
        return x
    else:
        func(x)

func(list_a)
print (list_a)
```

output:

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]